# how to fix nginx ssl error

Tags: ssl, nginx, certificate

I have domain, certificates and nginx.
3 file

```
private.key
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
domain.crt
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
PKCS.key
-----BEGIN PKCS7-----
-----END PKCS7-----
```

I edit /etc/nginx/sites-available/default file

```
ssl_certificate          /root/domain.crt;
ssl_certificate_key      /root/private.key;

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_ciphers AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH:!aNULL;
```

but when reload nginx got message

`nginx: [emerg] SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file("/root/private.key") failed (SSL: error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch)`

How I can fix it, what I do wrong?

Comment: The certificate doesn't match declared private key, there is no other advice as choose correct pair certificate/key.

Comment: I generate csr, past to generate in server and get domain&pkcs, private key generate openssl, where can be problem

Comment: please share the commands you have used to generate self signed cert